# Adding a Next and Previous button that reset the timer on a Jquery image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slider

I've been working on this slider for a bit, and I've got it to auto play with some nice simple Jquery markup. I decided I wanted to have the option to go to previous and next on the slider, but I'm not sure if it's possible with the set up I have. I've got a "Next" Button set up that moves to the next image. My problem lies in getting the timer to restart after you hit next in the code. Is this possible to do, am I just overlooking something? I also am wondering how to I create the equivalent of the "next" button for a "previous" button. Any help would be appreciated, since I've been banging my head against this one for while.

Here is the Jquery I'm using:

```
var time = 6000;     

function play() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var next = $(".slideshow .active").removeClass("active").next(".image");
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(".slideshow .image:first");
        }
        next.addClass("active");
    }, time);
}
play();

/*Start of function for next button  */

function forward() {
  $('.forward').click(function() {
      var go = $(".slideshow .active").removeClass("active").next(".image").addClass("active");
       if (!go.length) {
         go = $(".slideshow .image:first");
       }
       go.addClass("active");
    });
}

forward();
```

I've created a CodePen(http://codepen.io/Develonaut/pen/lLmkc) to try and work this out. I will gladly give credit on the CodePen for whoever helps. Thanks so much!

Comment: Acording to the codepen example it already goes back and forth

Comment: Yes, sorry in the time of asking this, I figured out how to make it go back and forth. No it was just a problem of resetting the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

You need to set the return value of your `setInterval` to a variable, then pass that variable to `clearInterval` to reset your timer. Do that on each press of your previous/next buttons, then call the `play` function again to start the timer from the beginning.

Here's an updated version of your [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mitFf).

Comment: PS: I sped up your transition timer from 6000ms to 3000ms in that CodePen for faster development... just mentioning that in case it throws you off or looks like a bug!

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! Thank you so much for helping me out. I'm still new to javascript and jquery so I wasnt even aware of "clearInterval." I'll be sure to give you credit in the CodePen. I would upvote you if I could, but my rep is too low. Sorry :(.

Comment: No prob, glad to help! You can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it rather than upvoting if it helped you. (Accepting answers boosts your rep a little too.)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

Store the interval id - setInterval() returns this for later use with clearInterval()

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function()...
```

Then clear & reset the interval when the button is pressed:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
play();
```